# Audio from Commodore 64 to line 1/4 inch line level

Tags: commodore-64, audio

I have a 1702 monitor for my C64. I use a cable that splits the video/audio from the C64 to the Red/Yellow/White thing. Something like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Cordon-Audio-Video-Cable-COMMODORE-64-C64-128-VIC-20-AV-Lead-New-6-7-12ft-/262846512046?hash=item3d32df7bae). The white cable is the audio. I believe this is an RCA connection.

I have an audio mixer that accepts line level. I would like to take the audio from the C64 to the audio mixer.

Do I simply get a female RCA to 1/4 inch plug? (so something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07D75BV1W)).

Comment: Be aware that "line level" means something different for pro-audio gear from what it means for consumer audio gear.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level#Nominal_levels The consumer audio line level is not as high.  If the channel you're plugging in to has a gain control, you may want to turn the gain up.  If it doesn't have a gain control, then you may just have to live with the fact that the signal is not as loud as you had hoped it would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. What you have on the RCA plug coming from the C64 is line level mono audio. You can connect it to a mixer using an RCA-to-phono adapter that fits your mixer. Often times, the phono jacks on mixers are for stereo input. So you might need an adapter that goes from Left+Right RCA inputs to a phono plug. Just plug the C64 output to either the Left or Right input, and adjust the mixer balance accordingly to filter the unused stereo input.

Comment: Phono plugs aka phonograph plugs *are* RCA plugs - you want to adapt RCA to a standard headphone plug (not the more modern smaller 3.5mm, the old 6.35mm/1'4" plug.  (This plug is sometimes called a "phone" plug, for "headphone plug", which might be the source of your confusion.  Sounds like it's best if we avoid using "phone plug" and "phono plug" completely :).)

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie Yep, I was confusing "phone" with "phono". Maybe I'll try using "TRS" plug in the future. Thanks for clarifying.